# In an Windows Azure application using CQRS architecture, what is the optimal choice for the read and write databases?

Tags: performance, azure-storage, cqrs

Building an application in Windows Azure with a CQRS architecture, what would be the optional storage solution for the read and write databases, if you are looking for maximum performance?

- Read: denormalized table
- Write: event storage

Currently Windows offer several solutions, such as:

- Azure SQL database
- Azure Table Storage
- Hadoop

Comment: There's also the option of DocumentDB to add to the mix.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on a few factors. Especially the write side depends on whether you use Event Sourcing or not.

(Edit: just re-read your question. Must have overlooked the event store bit.)

Have a look at Lokad.CQRS for an Azure-based example: http://lokad.github.com/lokad-cqrs/